# How to configure in nginx to allow ip and optional client certificate

Tags: nginx

Following case:

I need to configure my nginx that certain IPs can access it or you need a certificate for it.

```
server {
   . . .
   ssl_verify_client optional;
   location  /admin {
      allow XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;
      if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
         return 403;
        }
      deny all;
      }
   }
```

works for the IP, but when I want to add the certificate if-condition inside the location, of course I get the 403 error, because my workstation with the IP doesnt have the cert. Is there any way to have X OR Y?

Thanks!

Edit:

Solved it in a dirty way...

```
location  /admin {
  set $var_cert 0;

  if ($ssl_client_verify = SUCCESS) {
     set $var_cert 1;
  }

  if ($remote_addr = XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)  {
    set $var_cert 1;
  }

  if ($remote_addr = XXX.XXX.XXX.XXY)  {
    set $var_cert 1;
  }

  if ($var_cert = 0){
     return 403;
   }

  proxy_pass http://172.16.0.54/admin;


}
```

Well, it works.